# Lagrange multipliers or KKT problem

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the following: find the absolute max and absolute min of $f(x, y, z) = yz + xz$ over $V = \{(x, y, z) \in\mathbb{R}^3; 2x + y + z \leq 1; x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0\}$

*Attempts*

So first of all, $V$ is bounded and closed, hence it's compact. This means there do exist max and min (global). Even without starting any kind of calculation, I can smell the global min is at $(0, 0, 0)$, since we have a restriction over the three variables but they all can start from zero. The function cannot be negative, due to the conditions over $(x, y, z)$ so this "proves" the origin is the global minimum.

Yet I am having troubles in finding the global max. Also I wonder if there is a suitable way to find the global min too, without intuition.

The Lagrangian reads

$$L = yz + xz - \lambda(2x + y + z - 1)$$

And the associated system of equations (gradient plus constraint) reads

$$\begin{cases}
z - 2\lambda = 0 \\\\
z - \lambda = 0 \\\\
y + x - \lambda = 0
\\\\
\lambda(2x + y + z - 1) = 0 \\\\
2x + y + z - 1 \leq 0 
\end{cases}
$$

I avoided to write also the positive conditions on $(x, y, z)$.

Now from the first two equations it's obvious that $z = 0$. But then from the third and from the constraint I get $x = 1$, which turns into $y = -1$.

The point $(1, -1, 0)$ is not valid though.

I don't really know how to continue here, because I cannot say "suppose $\lambda \neq 0$ and then reason on the constraint for the first two equations implies $\lambda = 0$ and $z = 0$.

I am not capable to use KKT here, have no clue on how I would proceed with this.
Any help? Also $(0, 0, 0)$ does not emerge from here.

Comment: Are you sure you've used KKT correctly? The version I know of needs one support variable per (in-)equality constraint

Comment: @Sudix You mean like adding $\sigma x \geq 0$, $\rho y \geq 0$ and $\tau z \geq 0$ in addition to $\sigma x$, $\rho y$ and $\tau z$ in the Lagrangian? I tried but it becomes just a mess, and the solutions do not change, I think...

Comment: Without the inequalities $x,y,z\ge 0$ the problem has neither minimum or maximum, so they're strictly necessary. It becomes a mess in the sense that you get a case distinction into $2^4$ cases. That's more or less how it is expected to go, though - without anything we can make use of, each inequality constraint doubles the number of cases to handle. However, for your case, each resulting case is a linear program, so while the process may be tedious, it should give you a result.

Comment: If you want to save some work, you can (for the maximizer at least) first look only at $2x+y+z\le 1$ and argue that for any maximizer with $2x+y+z<1$ we can find a maximizer with $2x+y+z=1$ that is at least as good if not better.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda,s) = x z+y z+b x+\lambda _1 \left(s_1^2+2 x+y+z-1\right)+\lambda _2 \left(x-s_2^2\right)+\lambda _3 \left(y-s_3^2\right)+\lambda _4 \left(z-s_4^2\right)
$$

The stationary conditions gives

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{
b+2 \lambda _1+\lambda _2+z\\ 
\lambda _1+\lambda _3+z\\ 
\lambda _1+\lambda _4+x+y\\ 
s_1^2+2 x+y+z-1\\ 
x-s_2^2\\ 
y-s_3^2\\ 
z-s_4^2\\ 
\lambda _1 s_1\\ 
\lambda _2s_2\\ 
\lambda _3 s_3\\ 
\lambda _4 s_4}
$$

after substitution of $b = 0$ into the formal solutions, we have

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
f & x & z & y & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 & s_1^2 & s_2^2 & s_3^2 & s_4^2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{4} & 0 & -\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Here $s_i = 0$ means that the $i$-th constraint is active and $s_i > 0$ means that the solution point is internal to the corresponding constraint. The problem here is to administrate the $2^4$ possibilities of $\lambda_is_i = 0$